# add hover effect in bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I've created a profile picture structure in Bootstrap.

I want ask how can I add an hover effect which allows the apparition of a plus symbol, like = + , which indicates to the user that they can add a new image or something like it.

Thanks.

```css
@import url( 'https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css' );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <div class="form-group text-center" data-type="admins operators secretaries customers">
          <div class="profile-image-container">
             <div class="profile-header-img">
              <img class="img-circle" src="//lh3.googleusercontent.com/-6V8xOA6M7BA/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/rzlHcD0KYwo/photo.jpg?sz=120" />
              <!-- badge -->
             <div data-content="">
              <span class="label label-primary rank-label" style="font-size: 13px;">
              <label id="total-points">0</label>Points  </span>
             </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** gave parent div `.profile-header-img` the img's `width` and `height` to set `:hover` on it and prevent flickering:

```css
.profile-header-img {
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.glyphicon.glyphicon-plus-sign {
  display: none;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 50%;
  top: 44px;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  font-size: 32px;
}
.profile-header-img:hover .glyphicon.glyphicon-plus-sign {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group text-center" data-type="admins operators secretaries customers">
  <div class="profile-image-container">
    <div class="profile-header-img">
      <img class="img-circle" src="//lh3.googleusercontent.com/-6V8xOA6M7BA/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/rzlHcD0KYwo/photo.jpg?sz=120" />
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span>
      <!-- badge -->
      <div data-content="">
        <span class="label label-primary rank-label" style="font-size: 13px;">
          <label id="total-points">0</label>Points
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I want ask you if is possible put this plus sign on the image instead of the bottom?

Comment: Sure, I'll edit, for future reference try to include details like these in the question.

Comment: I noticed a strange flickering effect when I move the mouse over the plus icon, seems to hide and appear quickly, could you fix this?

Comment: Edited AgainMe, let me know if that's better.